# iOS 11.0 push view controller problem with navigationItem.searchController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I tried to push a child view controller with the searchBar display, there is a flashing gray bar appeared during the animation (see Figure 2), how can I fix that animation? Thank you.

Code:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  if title == nil {
    title = "Title"
  }

  if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
  }

  definesPresentationContext = true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)


  let vc = ViewController()
  vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
  navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

[image: step1]
[image: step2]
[image: step3]

Comment: Have you tried setting pushViewController animated to false?

Comment: Nope, cause I need this animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to `push` **the same** `ViewController()` which is embedded with `NavigationController`, that bar you saw might be the `navigationBar` of your `ViewController()`.

Try to create a new controller, then `push` to see whether the bar still exists, like so:

```
class NewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Then in your ViewController's `didSelectRowAt`, push the `NewController`, like so:

```
let newVC = NewController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(newVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but I wonder if this will lose the blur effect of navigationBar？

Comment: @Leo yes... but I feel set the table view or view’s background to white will solve the issue.

Comment: No, I tried, and neither of the two pieces of code solved the problem.

Comment: @Leo is your first VC, the tableview controller called ```ViewController```?

Comment: Both of them are.

Comment: Sorry, none of them works. And these is a question, `navigationController?.pushViewController(navNewVC, animated: true)`, push a navigationController is incorrect.

Comment: @Leo Oh sorry, my bad. That's already a navigationController. No need to put wrap it again. I've removed that part. Sorry about that and it didn't help.

Comment: Btw, I still think that's related to `nav bar`